# How knowledge of weapons (shastra) शस्त्र got lost?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, weapon

How did the knowledge of great weapons like Bramhastra got lost in Hinduism tradition? As can be seen in Ramayan and Mahabharat, Gurus used to give knowledge of weapons to their shishya which were then used to protect Dharma. But eventually this knowledge was lost and Bharat couldn't fight invaders. How did this happen? Why weren't Devas invoked through yajnas when Sanatan Dharma  followers were ethnically cleansed at the rate of millions by foreign invaders? At time of Mahabharat Indra himself helped Arjuna by granting him weapons. What happened now?

Comment: I have read 1000's of books including vedas,puranas,upanishad,tantras,maths and scientific ones and what i understand is that the entire existence is complete 0 which is the universal egg.And when spreaded lead to - and + values which when summed up has total value of 0.So to maintain the 0 their should always be - values too along with the + one's.So their can't be always fruits their must always be bad too.This four yuga cycle ensures that.Everything is karma

Comment: What makes you think all those shastras are real in the first place? Once you realize they are all mythological weapons, the question _How did the knowledge of those "weapons" got lost?_ doesn't even arise.

Comment: @sv I cannot see the past but I used shabda praman to reach that conclusion.

Comment: @Pravin RGMishra please do not post texts which do not give any answers.

Comment: @Wikash u are confused between answer and comment.

Comment: @Lokesh 'shabda praman' - for some people it just means the Vedas. Do you consider Itihasas and Puranas as also Shabda Pramana? So you believe Rama lived for 10,000 years and Dasharatha 60,000 years because it says so in Valmiki Ramayana?

Comment: @sv Yes, I trust the series of events mentioned in our itihas (history).

Comment: @sv & Wikash, you are stating your opinions that what's written in itihasaas and puranaas are not factual; Valmiki & Vyasa say they are factual. So Lokesh & I choose to place our trust in Valmiki's & Vyasa's statements instead of yours. There, that settles it.

Comment: @VijaySharma It's not just my opinion, it's the opinion of several scholars, Indian & Western. Vedas don't mention any of these astras. They're only found in Itihasas & Puranas. So the conclusion is obvious. 'There, that settles it' - for you, it settles, not for the rest of the world. Rest of the world believes in evidence. Demonstrable evidence.

Comment: @sv We are not bound to give you proof to show our Itihas happened before asking a question on this forum.

Comment: No one asked _you_ for proof, I was simply responding to the above comment. But as a reader I can certainly challenge your claims/assumptions that some supernatural weapon mentioned in Itihasas has to have existed.

Comment: @sv. And so we did responded to your challenge as a courtesy in-spite of the that fact it doesn't belong here but you are dragging this unnecessary with your biased opinions rather than facts. If dinosaurs fossils were not found you would have asked "how can you claim beings the size of mountains ever existed"?

Comment: 'If dinosaurs fossils were not found...' - there are some young earth creationists who claim dinosaur fossils are fake, earth was actually created 10,000 years ago, etc, you on the other hand are pushing it to the other extreme. I'm not biased, I'm simply asking for evidence of these so-called supernatural weapons. All you can present is mythological stories written about them. This is like showing a comic book and claiming spiderman is real.

Comment: @sv - you did not present any evidence either. So what I said does in fact settle it for you too. No? You yourself said what you wrote is the "opinion" of several................. That's the key word, opinion. What I said above still holds, you choose to place your trust in the opinions of "several scholars, Indian & Western"...of today's era. We chose to place our trust instead in the opinions of the rishis' of the old eras. So your entire argument behind negating reality of shastras is because of opinions of someone else. So please practice what you preach and find some evidence instead.

Comment: @VijaySharma Please understand how [burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)#Holder_of_the_burden) works. I'm not making any claims on these supernatural weapons, it is you who is making. So _you_ need to prove. Sorry, because it's mentioned in a book, doesn't cut it. After you prove these weapons did really exist, then you can go ahead and ask, what happened to these weapons, where are they now?

Comment: Oh, btw, "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence" @VijaySharma supernatural weapons like brahmastra and narayanastra are extraordinary claims/weapons so please furnish the extraordinary evidence.

Comment: @sv, by the 'burden of proof' logic, it is the burden of science to prove that sugar/saccharine tastes sweet. Go ahead and prove it to us if you can. One condition though - you can't ask us to taste it, because that is an invasion of my body/preference. *"Sorry, because it's mentioned in a book, doesn't cut it."* - ahahhaa, says the guy who believes in the existence of black holes, electrons etc just because some books/scientists mention it, without ever bothering to verify it yourself.

Comment: @VijaySharma , there will always be naysayers and atheists, even during Rama and Krishna's time. They talk as if they they're the flag bearers of scientific and rational thinking, but post them a simple question such as [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science-especially-when-it-comes-to-falsifiability) and they go cower in silence due to ignorance. just ignore the ignorant.

Comment: @sv. You try to apply philosophical logic mapped by western (scientific) boundaries in a Hindu discussion. That's kind of pointless don't you think? It's like judging a painting using different colors and tools used to create the painting. Although it may give you satisfaction, it servers no further purpose.

Comment: @sv. besides, "it's the opinion of several scholars" and "rest of the world believes in evidence"—Speak for yourself. Not for others. It's the arrogance of the western/scientific world to think that the whole world agrees with them or should agree with them.

Comment: "You try to apply ... western (scientific) boundaries in a Hindu discussion" - even Hindu philosophers applied the same principles although the terminology is a bit different (shabda, pratyaksha, anumana, etc.). See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2818/2995) answer which says even Vedas have to be rejected if they don't agree with reality/science. Scientists aren't the ones looking for these "divyastras" but it's people like OP who are wondering where did this "technology" go? For something to be lost, it has to first exist. @GabeHiemstra

Comment: @sv. Oh come on don't fool us by saying burden of proof lies on us. We are not making any claims here. We are just saying what's in the scriptures. This forum is for believers of Hinduism. You are coming in the way and saying our scriptures are comic books which is out the context of discussion here. That's common sense. By your logic every priest in the temple who believes in scriptures shares burden of proof to prove it to you. Really?

Comment: "We are not making any claims here." - You ARE making a claim, that these weapons are REAL. Then going on to ask, where the are they now? Outside these scriptures, these weapons don't exist. Yet, you are assuming they must be real and could've been used to thwart foreign invasions. In all this, you are not leaving even the slightest chance that these weapons could've been imaginary. "every priest in the temple who believes in scriptures shares burden of proof to prove it to you" - not every priest has the same question, maybe they are knowledgeable enough to tell exaggeration from reality.

Comment: @sv. Sri Vyasa and Sri Valmiki were not fictional writers. They wrote इतिहास = इति ह आस meaning "as it has been". This is a norm which every traditionally brought up Hindu believe. If you think otherwise you are making a claim not me.

Comment: @sv. The point is, you trust scientific evidence, while the OP relies on the revelation by sages. Both parties rely on external knowledge (i.e., not every fact of evidence is established through one's own understanding/experience). What is the difference? There isn't any. If you want to convince anyone that such weaponry doesn't exists, then you should provide every single fact yourself. The problem is you can't. Because you probably can't look into the past, nor do I expect you to have lived for thousands of years. So in my opinion, the discussion serves no purpose for this specific topic.

Comment: Your title mentions 'shastra' (physical weapon like a club, spear, etc) where as question body is talking about 'divyastras' like brahmastra. Both are separate things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Q:** How did the knowledge of great weapons like Bramhastra got lost in Hinduism tradition?

**Knowledge of great weapons like Brahmastra didn't get lost, they are still existing.**

Simple proof is that Parashurama has the knowledge of Brahmasatra and he is a chiranjeevi[[1]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/who-are-the-seven-immortals-chiranjeevi),[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiranjivi) i.e, he is alive now.

> Narada said, 'That tiger of Bhrigu's race (viz., Rama), was
>   well-pleased with the might of Karna's arms, his affection (for him),
>   his self-restraint, and the services he did unto his preceptor.
>   Observant of ascetic penances, **Rama cheerfully communicated, with due
>   forms, unto his penance-observing disciple, everything about the
>   Brahma weapon with the mantras for withdrawing it**. Having acquired a
>   knowledge of that weapon, Karna began to pass his days happily in
>   Bhrigu's retreat, and endued with wonderful prowess, he devoted
>   himself with great ardour to the science of weapons. One day Rama of
>   great intelligence, while roving with Karna in the vicinity or his
>   retreat, felt very weak in consequence of the fasts he had undergone.
>
> [[Section 3, Rajadharmanusasana Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a003.htm)

---

**Q:** As can be seen in Ramayan and Mahabharat, Gurus used to give knowledge of weapons to their shishya which were then used to protect Dharma. But eventually this knowledge was lost and Bharat couldn't fight invaders. How did this happen?

In Ramayan and Mahabharat, Gurus didn't give the knowledge of every weapon to every sishya. Inorder to give the knowledge of great weapons, *honest guru atleast verify the eligibility of the sishya and sometimes the purpose also*. If the sishya is either ineligible or asking weapon for bad purposes then the guru may not give the knowledge of weapon or may revoke it, if given earlier.

In Mahabharata, Drona did not give the knowledge of Brahmastra to Karna

> Beholding that Dhananjaya was superior to every one in the science of
>   weapons, Karna. one day approached Drona in private and said these
>   words unto him, 'I desire to be acquainted with the Brahma weapon,
>   with all its mantras and the power of withdrawing it, for I desire to
>   fight Arjuna. Without doubt, the affection thou bearest to every one
>   of thy pupils is equal to what thou bearest to thy own son. I pray
>   that all the masters of the science of weapons may, through thy grace,
>   regard me as one accomplished in weapons!' Thus addressed by him,
>   Drona, from partiality for Phalguna, **as also from his knowledge of the
>   wickedness of Karna, said, 'None but a Brahmana, who has duly observed
>   all vows, should be acquainted with the Brahma weapon, or a Kshatriya
>   that has practised austere penances, and no other.'** When Drona had
>   answered thus, Karna, having worshipped him, obtained his leave, and
>   proceeded without delay to Rama then residing on the Mahendra
>   mountains.
>
> [[Section 2,  Rajadharmanusasana Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a002.htm)

Parasurama revokes the remembrance of Karna's Brahmasatras knowledge at crucial time

> Unto the cheerless and trembling Karna, prostrated with joined hands
>   upon earth, that foremost one of Bhrigu's race, smiling though filled
>   with wrath, answered, '**Since thou hast, from avarice of weapons,
>   behaved here with falsehood, therefore, O wretch, this Brahma weapon
>   shalt not dwell in thy remembrance. Since thou art not a Brahmana,
>   truly this Brahma weapon shall not, up to the time of thy death, dwell
>   in thee when thou shalt be engaged with a warrior equal to thyself!
>   Go hence, this is no place for a person of such false behaviour as
>   thou! On earth, no Kshatriya will be thy equal in battle.**' Thus
>   addressed by Rama, Karna came away, having duty taken his leave.
>   Arriving then before Duryodhana, he informed him, saying, 'I have
>   mastered all weapons!'
>
> [[Section 3, Rajadharmanusasana Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a003.htm)

As I told early, the purpose is also very important. *Even the knowledge of weapons won't work if there is no purpose*. The presence or absence of weapons solely depends on the purpose only. If there is no purpose then the weapons will be absent i.e., they won't work.

Arjuna's weapons are absent while he was trying to safeguard many people from attacking enemies

> "Arjuna said, ‘....... Another incident has happened that is more
>   painful than this, O thou that art possessed of wealth of penances.
>   Repeatedly thinking of it, my heart is breaking. In my very sight, O
>   Brahmana, thousands of Vrishni ladies were carried away by the Abhiras
>   of the country of the five waters, who assailed us. **Taking up my bow
>   I found myself unequal to even string it. The might that had existed
>   in my arms seemed to have disappeared on that occasion. O great
>   ascetic, my weapons of diverse kinds failed to make their appearance.
>   Soon, again, my shafts became exhausted.** That person of immeasurable
>   soul, of four arms, wielding the conch, the discus, and the mace, clad
>   in yellow robes, dark of complexion, and possessing eyes resembling
>   lotus-petals, is no longer seen by me. .........’
>
> "Vyasa said, ‘......... All this has Time for its root. Time is,
>   indeed, the seed of the universe, O Dhananjaya. It is Time, again,
>   that withdraws everything at its pleasure. One becomes mighty, and,
>   again, losing that might, becomes weak. One becomes a master and rules
>   others, and, again, losing that position, becomes a servant for
>   obeying the behests of others. **Thy weapons, having achieved success,
>   have gone away to the place they came from. They will, again, come
>   into thy hands when the Time for their coming approaches.** The time
>   has come, O Bharata, for you all to attain to the highest goal. Even
>   this is what I regard to be highly beneficial for you all, O chief of
>   Bharata’s race."
>
> [[Section 8, Mausala Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/index.htm)

Thus possessing of weapons are useful only if time allows it. Else they are useless. So, one need to understand that **weapons make their appearances for establishing dharma at *proper times* by deserved person only**.

---

**Q:** Why weren't Devas invoked through yajnas when Sanatan Dharma followers were ethnically cleansed at the rate of millions by foreign invaders? At time of Mahabharat Indra himself helped Arjuna by granting him weapons. What happened now?

As you can see in Arjuna-Vyasa conversation that knowledge of weapons will not be present if some event is *destined* to happen. Although Arjuna possess knowledge of weapons, weapons did not make their appearance when thousands of Vrishni ladies were carried away by the Abhiras. This is because of the reason that the event need to be happened because of [curse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/is-it-true-that-thieves-kidnapped-some-of-krishnas-wives). The weapons made their appearances during Kurukshetra war, but not during the above mentioned attack.

Comment: Wow, completely awed by this explanation.

Comment: @Wikash_ Such people won't make their appearances open to all people.

Comment: If the knowledge still exists why do we not know of anyone who has a spiritual weapon?

Comment: @Wikash_ I already told in my comment.

Comment: @Hanugm that is seems very unlikely. The spiritual weapons used in the scriptures were quickly known to a lot of people. Surely, if someone possessed one we would have found out by now.

Comment: @Wikash_  *were quickly.known to a lot of people* -- not at all. Can you liist the names of people who can operate Brahmastra from scriptures?

Comment: @Hanugm correction: I meant other people knew of its existence. Anyway, as far as I know no one has ever used a spiritual weapon. Also, there is no proof such a weapon has ever existed. So I can safely conclude that they probably never existed in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108475/discussion-between-hanugm-and-wikash).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a competent Guru is required to understand a subject at deeper levels.  It applies to every branch of knowledge, be it SPIRITUALITY, or science or arts or something else.

Again, a competent Guru will not share all his knowledge to every passerby.  He/She should find a suitable disciple, who is competent enough to receive the knowledge.

Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa used [cry for worthy disciple](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=GcSeAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=Sri%20Ramakrishna%20cried%20for%20a%20suitable%20disciple,%20finally%20vivekananda%20came&source=bl&ots=OmDpVVyfva&sig=ACfU3U2rt8pz-avkfypXSPo_Y6sZF2uwQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHhdrQ7qXkAhUKQ48KHYqdDcY4ChDoATAKegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=Sri%20Ramakrishna%20cried%20for%20a%20suitable%20disciple%2C%20finally%20vivekananda%20came&f=false), while Narendranath (Swami Vivekananda) was searching for a worthy Guru.

--

It happens in every branch of science.  If one finds the divine weapons mentioned in the Epics like Ramayana or Puranas, but unable to find them in the present age, that situation can indicate innumerable reasons.

For example Sage Viswamitra did not impart his knowledge in divine weapons for every king of his times.  He waited for long for the birth of Sri Rama.

***A worthy Guru waits for a worthy disciple.***  That is the underlying principle.

---

Drona did not impart all his knowledge in archery to every one.  He imparted that knowledge to the Arjuna only.  Out of love towards his son Aswathama, he taught the latter the knowledge in Brahmasirsha, which is all powerful, which proved to be [detrimental to the mankind](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10012.htm).

Competency of disciple includes his/her balance of mind in utilising the knowledge that acquired and searching for a worthy disciple in turn for passing on the knowledge.

---

With the elimination of most of the kings in Mahabharata, the society degraded and humans lost the ability to acquire and retain knowledge of great things.

That was how we lost touch with the pure SPIRITUAL concepts of Vedas and got degraded into ritualistic society.

Similar was the case with other branches of knowledge, knowledge of divine weapons being one among them.

Comment: Lot of speculation here. Please add references for these statements: "With the elimination of most of the kings in Mahabharata, the society degraded and humans lost the ability to acquire and retain knowledge of great things." (besides, things like moon landing, nuclear weapons, internet, AI, etc. do not support this line of thinking).

Comment: There is a difference between interpretation and speculation.  Earlier in the case of Vedas also I stated Vedas contains spiritual aspects for which you didn't agree. It is your choice to accept my interpretation or not. @sv.

Comment: References are needed whether or not I as a reader agree with your views. I just review answers based on what's written in the answer and how well the references used support the statements made. Please don't take my comments personally.

Comment: I am not taking personally.  There was a mention about divine weapons in EPICs,  which are not available now. Competence in Guru as well as Disciple is crucial.  The knowledge of weapons was lost because there is no competency in subsequent generation. It is my interpretation but not speculation. @sv.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly the same as Astras (divine weapons), but in some way relevant to the question, are Yantras (mechanical devices). Knowledge regarding mechanical devices (including weaponry) was: 1) regarded as secret knowledge, not to be revealed to just anyone, for this would negate it’s essential effectiveness; and 2) expected to be learned from skilled artisans possessing their own collection of textual sources.

The closest resemblance between Astra and Yantra is possibly the bhūtavāhanayanta, or “mechanical beings animated by a kind of life force” (see bottom of answer).

The mechanical devices included weapons such as mechanical guardians and flying machines, and could be powered by either biological fuel, or some kind of life-force. Besides being aesthetically represented in poetic works of medieval India, they are also dealt with in the 12th century technical manual called the Samaranga-suradhara of king Bhoja.

Whether such weapons actually existed or not, isn't relevant to this discussion. A more important question is if the poetic representations of such fabulous weapons are reflections of that which was written about in technical manuals, or the other way around, i.e., whether the technical manuals (which contain ample instructions on building such devices) were based on descriptions found in poetic literature (which was based on the creative spirit and what was seen with the eye).

The Samaranga-sutradhara dedicates a large section dealing with, among others, mechanical weaponry.

> There is a whole category of male and female automata designed for various forms of automatic service (31.101–5), including automata with weapons who serve as guards (31.106–7). There are speaking and dancing birds, dancing horses, monkeys, and elephants (31.73–75).

In his study regarding mechanical devices, [Daud Ali](https://www.academia.edu/14928941/Bhoja_s_Mechanical_Garden_Translating_Wonder_across_the_Indian_Ocean_c._800-1100_CE) states that technical knowledge regarding mechanical deviecs was expected to be in the possession of learned artisans.

> It is of course an open question whether any of the machines in the Samarāṅganasūtradhāra were actually made at the courts of medieval Indian kings or were ever made at all. The text is mostly concerned with de-cribing and classifying machines—machines, it claims, that have been ob-served (31.82)—and provides technical knowledge only very sporadically. While the text speaks of specific technologies, like copper piping and elementary hydraulics, it gives no detailed or systematic instructions as to how to construct any of the machines it describes. **Like many other śāstras, it presupposes extra-textual knowledge possessed by the craftsman, technician, or machine-maker.**

It is also stated the absence of texts containing detailed instructions regarding mechanical devices was not due to the lack of knowledge thereof, but that revealing the secrets one would not attain the desired result:

> Bhoja explicitly acknowledges as much—**emphasizing that silence on the precise methods of constructing yantras was not due to any ignorance on the matter but rather to maintain secrecy—for without secrecy the fruits (phala) of the machine would not be attained (31.79–80)**. Wise men were to infer the procedure for making machines from Bhoja’s teaching by using their own intelligence (31.82). Revealing (vyak-tīkṛ) the secrets of machine-making, reasons Bhoja, would neither be in the interests of machine-makers nor give rise to fascination (kautuka) on the part of onlookers (31.81).

In one text (the Bṛhatkathāślokasaṃgraha) it can be found that knowledge regarding mechanical devices should be kept secret in order to guard one’s “way of life”.

> At this point a Brahmin tells the story of a certain carpenter of King Mahāsena by the name of Pukvasaka, who once accompanied the king’s en-tourage to Saurashtra, where he was so impressed by the skills of a young artisan by the name of Viśvila that he arranged the young man’s marriage to his daughter, Ratnāvalī, before returning home. Sometime later, Viśvila arrived at Pukvasaka’s home and was married to Ratnāvalī, with whom he fell deeply in love. Almost immediately Viśvila created incredible objects, like special wooden rice kernels that never softened but produced nutritious froth that a man could live on and cooking utensils that prolonged life and prevented disease—all in the manner of the yavanas. 
>   [...]
>   He then related that Viśvila had been discovered by Brahmadatta’s men in the late watches of the night departing and returning in a kind of large mechanical bird (yantrakukkuṭa). **When confronted, Viśvila had pleaded that sin will be incurred and so be it, but as soon as it is discovered, there will be a terrible consequence: the loss of my way of life.** For I want to spend my nights in the com-pany of my wife and my days carrying out the king’s orders. **Having said this, he implored the king for secrecy.**

Mechanical machines were envisioned to be powered by either a source of material fuel, or some sort of life force.

Bhoja mentions flying devices using boiling mercury as a source of fuel:

> The ākāśayantra [flying machine], according to Bhoja, was made from light wood, shaped like a giant bird, **and flew by the energy generated from vats of boiling mercury.** The association of the Bhoja’s preeminent machine with mercury, deemed the most precious and powerful of substances, is perhaps not surprising—mercury would soon become a key ingredient of Bhāskara’s twelfth-century “wheel of perpetual motion.”

More relevant to the discussion on Astras, is the description of mechanical flying machines fueled by some sort of life-force, as mentioned in the Lokapaññati, a 12th century Pali text from Burma:

> The Lokapaññati’s rendition of the story begins as a tale of two kingdoms: that of Pāṭaliputta (Sanskrit: Pātaliputra ) and the distant land of “Roma.” Roma, according to the story, was filled with makers of automata—**what the text calls literally “machines that were the vehicles of spirits,” bhūtavāhanayanta, or mechanical beings animated by a kind of life force.** In Roma, these machines carried out many functions, like commerce (buying and selling), agriculture, and protection. The secrets of this technology were fiercely guarded, and the machine-makers (yantakāras) of Roma were expected to report periodically to the royal court. If there was any prolonged absence, an automaton was sent to hunt down and kill the errant artisan, preventing the knowledge from spreading to other realms.

These specific yantras were capable of flying and acting as intelligent weaponry:

> The king of Roma devised a plan, and a metal chest containing an automaton with a sword was dispatched to Pāṭaliputta with messengers who announced that it was a chest full of gems for the emperor. Asoka, curious, called the son of the machine-maker to ex-amine the chest. After examining it carefully, he concluded that it was a trap and that inside the chest was an automaton that had been sent to kill him. He informed the emperor of this but the emperor, influenced by his ministers, remained unconvinced and commanded the artisan to open the box. The artisan, first taking leave to bid farewell to his family, returned and opened the box. **As he predicted, an automaton emerged, cut off his head, and then miraculously flew back to Roma.** Asoka praised the artisan and blamed his ministers. And here the story ends.

In his final words, he also states that mention of such mechanical devices in literary sources, should not be regarded as an attempt to “explain the magical”:

> This “importation” was not some sort of demystification, a case of the machine “explaining” the magical. Unlike post-Renaissance European contexts that tend to begin from the tacit assumption of an opposition between artifice and nature or between science and imagination, **our sources present us with a somewhat different mental mapping, where artifice supplemented and completed nature and where mechanics and magic would seem to converge on an aesthetics of wonder.** If anything, the magical and mechanical were mutually enhancing.

Comment: "Perhaps not exactly the same as Astras (divine weapons), but in some way relevant to the question, are Yantras (mechanical devices)" - OP's question is about divyastras (divine weapons) like brahmastra, not mechanical devices. "Whether such weapons actually existed or not, isn't relevant to this discussion." - it's very much relevant, if they did not exist what's the point of discussing them with regard to foreign invasions? Overall this answer is a commentary on the question and doesn't address the OP's main question about divyastras.

Comment: "OP's question is about divyastras (divine weapons) like brahmastra". No the OP says: "How did the knowledge of great weapons like..." he does not actually mention Divyastras. Besides, the implications that my answer entails regarding mechanical weapons can also be applied to the knowledge regarding astras. That's why I think this answer is relevant in some way. "if they did not exist what's the point of discussing them": Because the question is about the "knowledge", not about their "existence". This answer addresses the knowledge regarding advanced weaponry.